# Android: How to search image-name (=string) in drawable directory and show it in an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

Firebase tells my app, an image name. 
Example: test.jpg (as a String)

This image exists in my drawable directory.

My app should read the image name and search this image in the drawable directory and display it in an ImageView.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
iv.setImageResource(resId);
```

sets to the `ImageView` with id `iv` the image with name (id) `imagename` (excluding .jpg) after finding its id in folder `drawable`.  
If your code is in an activity, replace `context` with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **stackoverflow**.
Try bellow code in your button click:

```
EditText editText=findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
String text=editText.getText().toString();

int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(text, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
ImageView imageView=findViewById(R.id.yourImageView);
imageView.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Now, if you type image name (without extension) in EditText and click the button, image will be shown.